# NDK, work with FloatBuffer as parameter

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, nio

I'm working with NDK and native buffer. I have the following code:

Java class definition with native method:

```
public class MyNDK {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("MyLibrary");
    }

    public native void workWithFloatBuffer(FloatBuffer buffer, int base, int size);

}
```

Native code implementation (i have test its definition and it's ok):

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_xcesco_myapplication_MyNDK_workWithFloatBuffer(JNIEnv *env, jobject object, jobject input, jint base, jint size)
{
    jfloat *buffer =(jfloat *) env->GetDirectBufferAddress(input);

    for (int i=base;i<size;i++)
    {
        buffer[i]=i*2.0f;
    }
}
```

And the code used in an activity to test the result:

```
    FloatBuffer buffer= ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4*10).asFloatBuffer();
    (new MyNDK()).workWithFloatBuffer(buffer, 0,4);

    for (int i=0; i< 4;i++) {
        Log.i("BLA", "value["+i+"]="+buffer.get(i));
    }
```

Current result on log is:

```
value[0]=0.0
value[1]=9.0E-44
value[2]=4.6007E-41
value[3]=6.8966E-41
```

That's very different from the aspected result of

```
value[0]=0.0
value[1]=2
value[2]=4
value[3]=6
```

What's it wrong?

Comment: `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(10)` <-- wouldn't you need more than 10 bytes for 4 floats?

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I've already change the allocation size, but i didn't update the code. Anyway, the result is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the values in [a float converter](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) was informative:

9.0E-44 equals 0x00000040
4.6007E-41 equals 0x00008040

2.0 equals 0x40000000
4.0 equals 0x40800000

So what you've got here is an endianness problem. You could try declaring your `FloatBuffer` as follows:

```
FloatBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(16)
                               .order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)
                               .asFloatBuffer();
```

Or you could reversing the endianness of the values in your C++ code if you prefer that.

Comment: Can I assume that all Android devices are little endian?

Comment: I'm not sure about the MIPS-based Android devices. But those are very rare.

Comment: I thought it is better to use the `ByteOrder.nativeOrder()` as the native libraries expect the buffers in native order.